# Is Wade-Giles "Shih" pronounced the same as Pinyin "Shi"?

Tags: pronunciation, pinyin, transliteration

I was wondering if the Wade-Giles pronunciation of "Shih", as in "Chiang Chieh-shih" is pronounced the same as the Pinyin pronunciation of "Shi" as in "Jiang Jieshi".
Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked any correspondance tables, such as [this one on pinyin.info](http://www.pinyin.info/romanization/compare/wadegiles.html)? Does that table answer your question?

Comment: Wade-Giles is just an antiquated pinyin, pronunciation is the same.

Comment: Look at Chiang Kai-shek on Wikipedia to see his several names in characters,  Wade-Giles, and Hanyu pinyin.

Answer (score 1):

If you are considering the phonemes only and not taking into account tone, then the answer is yes. But if you want to get the most accurate answer about whether or not they correspond to the same sound in Chinese, then you should include a tone.

Shí and shih2 (the 2 should be superscripted) are both romanizations of the character 石 in the Chinese name 蔣介石.